# How to annotate injector.getInstance?

Tags: java, junit, dependency-injection, guice

I want to inject an instance from `Guice injector` in my unitTest.

Which diffrentiator can I use?

I know `@annotation` mechanism is used in ctor params

but junit doesn't allow ctor with params.

should I use `class fields' @annotation`?

```
 public void setUp() throws Exception {
    RoutingResponseRepository routingResponseRepository = injector.getInstance(RoutingResponseRepository.class);
}
```

e.g.

I want

`@firstType RoutingResponseRepository`

and

`@secondType RoutingResponseRepository`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Injector.getInstance(Key)`](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html#getInstance-com.google.inject.Key-):

```
injector.getInstance(Key.get(RoutingResponseRepository.class, firstType.class))
```

When referring to a binding, Guice internally uses an immutable [Key](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Key.html) instance, which refers to an annotation status (a binding annotation class, a binding annotation instance, or no binding annotation) combined with a type (a class literal, a Type instance, or a TypeLiteral). Matching this matrix, there are 9 different overloads of `Key.get`, which is the static factory method to get these Key objects. Overloads that take `Class<?>` are offered just for the sake of convenience.

In general, any time you want to represent a parameterized or annotated type (like in `getInstance` or `bind`), you can use an overload that takes a Key instead.

Answer (score 3):

For testing, you could just inject into your test-case-instance. Then you can use your injection-points just as you would in production code:

```
@Inject
@SecondType 
private RoutingResponseRepository;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    Guice.createInjector().injectMembers(this);
}
```

without caring about Types and Keys.